# available wso2 claim uri

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Having a task to get the details of password last update date to calculate remaining days for expiring.

I tried using Claim uri http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginAttempts and http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked to get the details on **failed attempts** and **status of the account**. which worked as expected, but to get the password last updated date, i require a claim uri and the attribute to fetch the field value.

Could you please help in understanding this?

Answer (score 0):

There is claim uri that is defined as `http://wso2.org/claims/passwordTimestamp` But i do not think it has been used in Identity Server. [This](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/4.2.2/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/mgt/IdentityMgtEventListener.java) is latest code of identity management listener that implements these functions.  I can not find usage of this claim

Comment: Thanks, Am using this uri and updating with timestamp of password last update date, and also able to retrieve it back.